# Why Won't Arduino Intellisense Work in VSCode?

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code

I installed the Arduino extension [Arduino extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino) in VSCode which is supposed to include intellisense however it doesn't seem to be working. This is my c_cpp_properties.json:

[image: c_cpp_properties.json]

And here is an example of the intellisense not working:

[image: intellisense not working]

As you can see, intellisense should be able to predict the keyword `Serial` however it does not.

I have Command Line Tools installed. Is there a missing directory that I should include in the "includePath" property.

Answer (score 12):

add the missing lines into your c_cpp_properties.json (and change some filename to mac equivalent)
especially with `"defines": [ "USBCON" ]` to make Serial class to work with intellisense

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "<arduino ide installation folder>\\tools\\**",
                "<arduino ide installation folder>\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\**",
                "<arduino ide installation folder>\\hardware\\tools\\**",
                "<arduino ide installation folder>\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino"
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [
                "<arduino ide installation folder>\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino\\Arduino.h"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "<arduino ide installation folder>\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\bin\\avr-gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "defines": [
                "USBCON"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: This is the solution for me with an Arduino Uno and WeMos D1 R1 Mini ESP8266 (April 2019)!
- "<User Documents>\\Arduino\\libraries\\**", essential for libraries
- ForcedInclude was essenital for libraries
- USBCON was essential for Serial

Comment: In my environment, library locations are handled by the extension when you use the library function to add/install library

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try addding this paths to "browse" as in "includePath"

```
   "browse": {
      "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false,
      "path": [
        "arduino_install_dir/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include",
        "${workspaceRoot}"
      ]
    },
```